Struct methods by proxy to inplace methods, with possible RVO or NRVO
Suppose I have a struct, and I am trying to define a method that could:

modify the instance of the struct inplace
do the normal thing and return a new instance while leaving the original instance unmodified.

I would think that what I want to do in the implementation is define the inplace method, and then define the normal method by proxy. For the sake of example let us consider a simple struct that has an int num member, and can add another int to it. I can imagine coding this in two different ways: either have add_inplace be a void return, or have add_inplace return *this. Here are the two implementation:
struct myStruct_impl1{
  int num = 0;
  void add_inplace(const int& other)
  {
    num += other;
    return;
  }
  myStruct_impl1 add(const int& other) const
  {
    myStruct_impl1 tmp(*this);
    tmp.add_inplace(other);
    return tmp;
  }
};

struct myStruct_impl2{
  int num = 0;
  myStruct_impl2& add_inplace(const int& other)
  {
    num += other;
    return *this;
  }
  myStruct_impl2 add(const int& other) const
  {
    return myStruct_impl2(*this).add_inplace(other);
  }
};

What I am thinking now is that in myStruct_impl1 method add the named tmp is returned, so there is the chance to perform NRVO by the compiler (even though it is not guarantied). On the other hand in myStruct_impl2 the method add is returning from the return of an lvalue reference (the return of add_inplace). What happens now? Is this considered a temporary and possibly RVO will be performed (guarantied after c++17)? Am I thinking of part of this incorrectly? Am I doing all this wrong and there is a better way to think about the case of having methods defined by proxy to inplace methods?
******** UPDATE *********
As @zerocukor287 suggested in the comments, I made copy/move constructors and assignments, and the destructor, print them selves when called. Here is the code:
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct myStruct_impl1{
  int num;

  myStruct_impl1() : num(0) {};
  myStruct_impl1(const int& other) : num(other) {}

  myStruct_impl1(const myStruct_impl1& other)     : num(other.num) { std::cout << "called impl1 Ctor" << std::endl; }
  myStruct_impl1(myStruct_impl1&& other) noexcept : num(std::move(other.num)) { std::cout << "called impl1 Mtor" << std::endl; }

  myStruct_impl1& operator=(const myStruct_impl1& other)     { std::cout << "called impl1 Cass" << std::endl; num = other.num; return *this; }
  myStruct_impl1& operator=(myStruct_impl1&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "called impl1 Mass" << std::endl; num = std::move(other.num); return *this; }

  ~myStruct_impl1() { std::cout << "called impl1 Dest" << std::endl; }

  void add_inplace(const int& other)
  {
    num += other;
    return;
  }
  myStruct_impl1 add(const int& other) const
  {
    myStruct_impl1 tmp(*this);
    tmp.add_inplace(other);
    return tmp;
  }
};

struct myStruct_impl2{
  int num;

  myStruct_impl2() : num(0) {};
  myStruct_impl2(const int& other) : num(other) {}

  myStruct_impl2(const myStruct_impl2& other)     : num(other.num) { std::cout << "called impl2 Ctor" << std::endl; }
  myStruct_impl2(myStruct_impl2&& other) noexcept : num(std::move(other.num)) { std::cout << "called impl2 Mtor" << std::endl; }

  myStruct_impl2& operator=(const myStruct_impl2& other)     { std::cout << "called impl2 Cass" << std::endl; num = other.num; return *this; }
  myStruct_impl2& operator=(myStruct_impl2&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "called impl2 Mass" << std::endl; num = std::move(other.num); return *this; }

  ~myStruct_impl2() { std::cout << "called impl2 Dest" << std::endl; }

  myStruct_impl2& add_inplace(const int& other)
  {
    num += other;
    return *this;
  }
  myStruct_impl2 add(const int& other) const
  {
    return myStruct_impl2(*this).add_inplace(other);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  myStruct_impl1 ex1(10);
  myStruct_impl2 ex2(10);

  int y = 42;

  std::cout << "----------- Impl 1 -----------" << std::endl;
  ex1.add(y);
  std::cout << "----------- Impl 2 -----------" << std::endl;
  ex2.add(y);
  std::cout << "-----------  END  ------------" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

Code was compiled with g++ 11.4.0 and g++ 13.1.0, with std=c++11,17,20, and with and without -O3. In all case the output was the following:
----------- Impl 1 -----------
called impl1 Ctor
called impl1 Dest
----------- Impl 2 -----------
called impl2 Ctor
called impl2 Ctor
called impl2 Dest
called impl2 Dest
-----------  END  ------------
called impl2 Dest
called impl1 Dest

So it seams returning from the return of the lvalue reference in Impl2 causes two calls to the ctor, and should probably be avoided in this type of cases. However, @Marek R provided a godbolt snippet in the comments where the assembly looks identical in both cases? I am not sure how to reason on what the code is doing.

Looks like a micro-optimization.

You can test it yourself by creating user defined copy and move constructors that let's say write to std::cout. Then create several use cases and see what's happening.

Returning by lvalue reference, doesn't involve any rvo/nrvo etc afaik.

For compiler there is no significant difference: https://godbolt.org/z/3nPd6xGfP


What I am thinking now is that in myStruct_impl1 method add the named tmp is returned, so there is the chance to perform NRVO by the compiler (even though it is not guarantied).

Exactly.

On the other hand in myStruct_impl2 the method add is returning from the return of an lvalue reference (the return of add_inplace). What happens now? Is this considered a temporary and possibly RVO will be performed (guarantied after c++17)?

Reference is not a temporary.
and RVO won't apply to myStruct_impl2(*this).
Your return statement would be equivalent to
return myStruct_impl2(myStruct_impl2(*this).add_inplace(other));

So a copy constructor would be called.
The outer/extra temporary won't be materialized.
Implementation from myStruct_impl1 is the most optimized way (even if NRVO doesn't apply, you will have a extra move, instead of the extra copy) if you reuse add method.
The optimal way would be to rewrite without reusing the other method:
myStruct_impl3 add(const int& other) const
{
    return myStruct_impl3{this->num + other.num};
}


However, @Marek R provided a godbolt snippet in the comments where the assembly looks identical in both cases? I am not sure how to reason on what the code is doing.

Compiler might do other optimizations following as-if rule. No output involved, just an int member to modify. The extra copy can be removed.
You might even see than add_inplace is not even called.
